# Is Ganesha ever worshiped by Madhura bhava?

Tags: worship, ganesha, bhakti

I've come across information on madhura bhava for both Vishnu (in the form of Krishna) and Shiva (in the form of Bhikshatana). But I was curious if Ganesha is ever worshiped this way? I know there is a Ganapatya sect, but what would they think of worshiping Ganesha by madhura bhava? Do they have a precedent set for this sort of worship, or maybe a precedent against it? For example, are there any poets who wrote madhura bhava style love poetry to Ganesha similar to Mirabai? Or any scriptural references that mention Ganesha being worshiped by madhura bhava? Or maybe there is a particular form or avatar of Ganesha which madhura bhava is commonly directed to?